# How to use Modals for Chrome Extensions (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog, alert

I'm trying to create a basic Chrome Extension that comes up with some kind of alert when the extension is clicked. I was able to create this using the following Javascript:

```
 function spoilerAlert() {
       confirm('Warning, there are spoilers on this page!'); 
       }
    
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', spoilerAlert())
```

and then adding the following to my HTML file:

```
<body onload = 'spoilerAlert()'>
```

whilst also referencing the .js file in the body:

```
<script language='javascript' src='popup.js'></script>
```

This works, but since the extension icon is in the corner of chrome, when it is clicked the alert box appears in the top corner of my browser, mostly off screen:
[image]

This box can be moved but obviously this is not ideal. After extensive googling it appears that the positioning of these built in alerts cannot be changed, and everywhere suggests using a customised dialogue box. So I have been trying to use a modal (which seems to be more appropriate for what I want to achieve in the long run which is considerably more complicated than where I am up to currently), but applying the same logic as before does not seem to work with modals. I have changed the Javascript is the following:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
function spoilerAlert() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', spoilerAlert())
```

and in the HTML file I have:

```
  <body onload = 'spoilerAlert()'>
   <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p> Spoiler Alert </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

I also have some styling in the head. However the HTML no longer seems to be reading the Javascript, is ignoring all of the styling and is simply giving me this:
[image]

which seems to be the complete default. Any suggestions on how to get my HTML to read the modal functions in my Javascript file would be appreciated, or any other easier ways to create a custom dialogue box. Please note my Javascript knowledge is limited! Thanks.

Comment: 1. inline js doesn't work in chrome extension pages - use a separate js file 2. `spoilerAlert()` is a function invocation, not a reference required in addEventListener - use `spoilerAlert`.

Comment: Thank you. I know javascript does not work inline with chrome extensions but the line inside the body tag seemed to work for the confirm box. How else can I use the onload function? What can I put in the separate .js file that has the same effect as `<body onload = 'spoilerAlert()'/>`? Sorry I perhaps did not make it clear in my original question that all of my Javascript (bar the body tag) is written in a separate file.

Comment: You already have `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',`, which would do what you want if you followed the other statement from wOxxOm, which was that `spoilerAlert()` is a function invocation, not a function reference. You need to pass a function reference to `addEventListener()`. For example: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',spoilerAlert);`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].